# classification of audio notes based on first few seconds

Tags: audio, speech-recognition, voice-recording, voice-recognition, classification

I record audio notes on my recorder, and each belongs to a certain category ("work", "parenting", "miscellaneous", etc.). At the beginning of each recording, I say the name of the category, then stay silent for a few seconds, and only then I begin talking.

I'm looking for software which classifies audio notes, either automatically or maybe given as input the voice recordings for each category name, or in any feasible way.

To my knowledge, there are ways to compare whole audio files, but I don't know how to do this particular job because the duration of the category names at the beginning of different clips might be different, there might be shifts, etc. I do try to enunciate the category names consistently, but there will be differences nonetheless.

I'd greatly appreciate recommendations for software that can do this.

- operating system: either Windows or Mac-OS or Linux is fine
- any audio format is fine
- price: the lower the better of course, but I can manage a couple of hundred $ if the software does exactly the intended task.